# Time conversion across time zones

Tags: outlook, meetings, microsoft-teams

I need to write to colleagues and customers across multiple time zones. Most often east coast, west coast, eastern Europe and India. E.g. *“Are you available tomorrow 10:00 am EDT / 7:00 am PDT / 5:00 pm EEST / 7:30 pm IST for a quick call?”* I have an android app with time table and looking up for the time manually. Is there some automatic way? Or a MS Teams / MS Outlook plugin?

Answer (score 1):

You can try https://tzpro.org. It also has a "translate" option. You write the sentence in one time zone, and it translates to multiple time zones. Exactly as you mentioned above.

There is plenty of other options, but it usually provides a world clock or a timetable - and you have to copy/paste the values by yourself. It can be tedious if you need to provide several options (e.g., *I am free at 1, 2, and 3 pm.*)

Answer (score 0):

give https://timezoneconverterapp.com/ a try. I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).